# In iOS how to stretch header image only in one side to 100%?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an image which is a header for the screen. In the right part of it there is a text. In the left part there is simple pattern in 2 colours. I need to stretch image when rotating to landscape but to avoid stretching the text part. I want to stretch only left (simple 2 colours part), so the stretch was not visible at all. Is it possible with auto-layout and how, because I can not figure out how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. You need to use slicing tool in Xcode and cut the image into several pieces, where middle will contain text.

Comment: 10x, this is what I need

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your image to a stretchable one using resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:. You can use the cap insets to define the part of the image that you don't want to stretch.